# T is not a valid type for non-type template parameter

Tags: c++

Can't compile the code below:

```
#include <array>

template <class T, T state>
class stateless
{
public:

    void f() { /* do something with m_val*/; }

private:

    static inline constexpr T m_val = state;
};

struct A
{
    int x;

    int GetX() const { return x; }
};

template <class T, class ReturnType>
using FuncPtr = ReturnType(T::*)() const;

template <class T, class ReturnType>
class func_getter
{
public:

    using object_type = T;
    using value_type = ReturnType;

    using MyFuncPtr = FuncPtr<T, ReturnType>;

    constexpr func_getter(MyFuncPtr p) : m_p(p) {}

    constexpr ReturnType operator() (const T& val) const
    {
        return (val.*m_p)();
    }

private:

    MyFuncPtr m_p;
};

int main()
{
    {
        using Array = std::array<int, 3>;
        constexpr std::array<int, 3> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
        stateless<Array, a> s;
    }

    {
        constexpr A a = { 1 };
        stateless<A, a> s;
    }

    // All the code above compiles, but the code below does not.

    {
        using Getter = func_getter<A, int>;
        constexpr Getter g(&A::GetX);
        stateless<Getter, g> s;
    }

    {
        constexpr func_getter g(&A::GetX);
        stateless<decltype(g), g> s;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

MSVC 2022 error:

```
error C2993: 'Getter': is not a valid type for non-type template parameter 'state'
```

Comment: Basically `Getter` is `func_getter<A, int>` which has a private member so it can't be used as a non-type template parameter.

Comment: @user12002570 it is strange that std::array's data member is public.

Comment: Yup, it is required there for it(`std::array`) to be an aggregate.

Comment: It's not particularly strange for `std::array`'s data to be public, it's meant as a drop-in replacement for C style arrays. `std::array::data()` exposes it just as much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **problem** is that `Getter`(aka `func_getter<A, int>`) is not a [structural type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.param#7) so it can't be used as a non-type template parameter as per [temp.param](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.param#6) :

> 6. A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (possibly cv-qualified) types:
>
> - **a structural type** (see below),
> - 
> - 
>
> 7. **A structural type is one of the following**:
>
> - 
> - 
> - a literal class type with the following properties:
>
>   - **all** base classes and **non-static data members are public** and non-mutable and
>   - 

(emphasis mine)

And since `Getter` has a private *non-static* data member `m_p`, it violates the above rule and so is not a structural type and cannot be used as a non-type template parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The full error is:

```
template <class T, T state>
                     ^
pp.cpp:65:9: note: while substituting prior template arguments into non-type template parameter 'state' [with T = func_getter<A, int>]
        stateless<Getter, g> s;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pp.cpp:44:15: note: 'func_getter<A, int>' is not a structural type because it has a non-static data member that is not public
    MyFuncPtr m_p;
```

The important point is *`'func_getter<A, int>' is not a structural type`*.
A structural type cannot have private field.

Answer (score 2):

g++'s error message is more helpful here:

> error: 'func_getter<A, int>' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter because it is not structural.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) list the requirements

> A non-type template parameter must have a structural type, which is one of the following types (optionally cv-qualified, the qualifiers are ignored):
>
> - lvalue reference type (to object or to function);
> - an integral type;
> - a pointer type (to object or to function);
> - a pointer to member type (to member object or to member function);
> - an enumeration type;
> - `std::nullptr_t`;
> - a floating-point type;
> - a literal class type with the following properties:
>
>   - all base classes and non-static data members are public and       non-mutable and
>   - the types of all base classes and non-static data members are structural types or (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof.

I.e. the problem is `MyFuncPtr m_p;` is `private`.

[See coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94ab7c0139135323)